# JSF 2.0 AJAX re-renders more than the IDs I specify. Not sure if I have a fundamental misunderstanding or just a bug

Tags: java, jsf

When I click on the logOutButton it seems as though it's re-rendering the ajaxR element also.  I would expect it to only re-render the IDs I have in the f:ajax render attribute.  Or maybe it's re-rendering the whole page.  The question is, why's it rendering the ajaxR element and/or the whole page and not just the IDs I've specified.

To make sure I'm clear:  when I click on the logout button, the ajaxR element does not get rendered because of rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>
<h:head>
    <title>SandBox</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>SandBox</h1>    
    <h:form id="form1">

        Registration:<br></br>
        Email: <h:inputText value="#{regBean.email}"></h:inputText><br></br>
        User Id: <h:inputText value="#{regBean.userId}"></h:inputText><br></br>
        Password: <h:inputText id="passR" value="#{regBean.password}"></h:inputText><br></br>

        <h:outputText rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" id="nodeL" value="Good Luck: #{userIdBean.userId}" style="font-weight:bold" /><br></br>

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{regBean.storeUserId}" />
        <h:commandButton id="logOutButton" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" value="Log Out" type="submit" action="#{loginBean.logoutUser}" >
            <f:ajax event="keyup" render="nodeL logOutButton"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <br></br>

    <h:outputText rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" value="AJAX Response: #{userIdBean.userId}"></h:outputText>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here's a snippet of the bean code.

```
public String logoutUser(){
        userIdBean.setIsLoggedIn(false);
        userIdBean.setUserId(null);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes in the code:

1. The `<f:ajax event>` in an `UICommand` component like `<h:commandButton>` must be set to `action`. You can also just leave the `event` attribute altogether away, it will then default to a sane default (which is `action` for command components and `valueChange` for input components).

   ```html
   <h:commandButton id="logOutButton" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" value="Log Out" type="submit" action="#{loginBean.logoutUser}" >
       <f:ajax render="nodeL logOutButton"/>
   </h:commandButton>
   ```
2. The `<f:ajax render>` client ID should refer a component which is *always* rendered to the client side. It will then be exactly the HTML representation of that component which will be updated by JavaScript. If the HTML representation of that component is not JSF-rendered to the client side because the `rendered` of the component is `false`, then JavaScript has nothing to find and update and in effect "nothing" will happen. Set it to for example `@form` which indicates the entire form:

   ```html
   <h:commandButton id="logOutButton" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" value="Log Out" type="submit" action="#{loginBean.logoutUser}" >
       <f:ajax render="@form" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

   or some common wrapper component which is always rendered:

   ```html
   <h:panelGroup id="group">    
       <h:outputText id="nodeL" value="Good Luck: #{userIdBean.userId}" style="font-weight:bold" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" />
       <br></br>
       <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{regBean.storeUserId}" />
       <h:commandButton id="logOutButton" value="Log Out" action="#{loginBean.logoutUser}" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}">
           <f:ajax render="group" />
       </h:commandButton>
       <br></br>
       <h:outputText value="AJAX Response: #{userIdBean.userId}" rendered="#{userIdBean.isLoggedIn}" />
   </h:panelGroup>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use "`click`" event instead of "`keyup`" as below.

```
<f:ajax event="click" render="nodeL logOutButton"/>
```